# Adding properties to uploaded content in Alfresco

Tags: metadata, alfresco

I am using Alfresco Web Quick Start to create a basic CMS website. I was wondering if someone could explain how to add properties/metadata to content which I have uploaded. For example if I have a gallery of images (with the default metadata of Author, Published, Size and Mime Type) and wanted to have a data taken property etc, how would I implement this?

I have done some research but am yet to find a concrete solution, any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Anyone know if this answer is still the correct solution for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a royal pain in the ass.

First you need to create a Model. Inside that model you need to create an Aspect. All this goes in XML file #1.

Then you need a context file to register the aspect. This is XML file #2.

And a properties files to give the aspect a friendly name.

And a web-site-custom-config to list all of the properties that were listed in XML file 1. This is XML file #3

And you need a share-custom-config. This has a different format from XML file #3, but serves the same purpose.

And finally you need to create a rule that automatically applies the aspect to each item in a folder.

Reference: http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2010/02/25/adding-custom-aspect-support-in-alfresco-share/

---

share-custom-config.xml

```
<alfresco-config>

    <!-- Repository Library config section -->
    <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="RepositoryLibrary" replace="true">
        <!--
         Whether the link to the Repository Library appears in the header component or not.
        -->
        <visible>true</visible>
    </config>

    <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">

        <!--
         Used by the "Manage Aspects" action

         For custom aspects, remember to also add the relevant i18n string(s)
            cm_myaspect=My Aspect
        -->
        <aspects>
            <!-- Aspects that a user can see -->
            <visible>
                <aspect name="my:sampleProps" />
                <aspect name="ac:androidContentProps" />
            </visible>

            <!-- Aspects that a user can add. Same as "visible" if left empty -->
            <addable>
            </addable>

            <!-- Aspects that a user can remove. Same as "visible" if left empty -->
            <removeable>
            </removeable>
        </aspects>
    </config>

    <config evaluator="node-type" condition="cm:content">
        <forms>
            <form>
                <field-visibility>
                    <!-- fields from my example aspect -->
                    <show id="my:propOne" />
                    <show id="my:propTwo" />
                    <show id="my:propInt" />
                    <show id="my:propFloat" />
                    <show id="my:propDateTime" />
                    <show id="my:propDate" />
                    <show id="my:propBoolean" />
                    <show id="my:propQName" />
                    <show id="my:propCategory" />
                    <show id="my:propNodeRef" />
                    <show id="my:propPath" />
                    <!-- fields for android content -->
                    <show id="ac:propNotify" />
                    <show id="ac:propNotificationSummary" />
                    <show id="ac:propArchiveDate" />
                    <show id="ac:propPublishDate" />
                    <show id="ac:propPriority" />
                    <show id="ac:propRegion" />
                    <show id="ac:propMarket" />
                    <show id="ac:propDistrict" />
                    <show id="ac:propStore" />
                </field-visibility>
            </form>
        </forms>
    </config>


    <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Remote">
        <remote>
            <endpoint>
                <id>alfresco-noauth</id>
                <name>Alfresco - unauthenticated access</name>
                <description>Access to Alfresco Repository WebScripts that do not require authentication</description>
                <connector-id>alfresco</connector-id>
                <endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s</endpoint-url>
                <identity>none</identity>
            </endpoint>

            <endpoint>
                <id>alfresco</id>
                <name>Alfresco - user access</name>
                <description>Access to Alfresco Repository WebScripts that require user authentication</description>
                <connector-id>alfresco</connector-id>
                <endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s</endpoint-url>
                <identity>user</identity>
            </endpoint>

            <endpoint>
                <id>alfresco-feed</id>
                <name>Alfresco Feed</name>
                <description>Alfresco Feed - supports basic HTTP authentication via the EndPointProxyServlet</description>
                <connector-id>http</connector-id>
                <endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s</endpoint-url>
                <basic-auth>true</basic-auth>
                <identity>user</identity>
            </endpoint>

            <endpoint>
                <id>activiti-admin</id>
                <name>Activiti Admin UI - user access</name>
                <description>Access to Activiti Admin UI, that requires user authentication</description>
                <connector-id>activiti-admin-connector</connector-id>
                <endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/activiti-admin</endpoint-url>
                <identity>user</identity>
            </endpoint>
        </remote>
    </config>

</alfresco-config>
```

Comment: You'll also likely want a way to automatically extract that data from your files, via the Metadata Extractor Service. However, if you pick one of the built in Aspects (eg exif:exif) then all the configuration for extracting that data from files is already present!

Comment: Hey Jonathan :) Thanks for the quick response. I followed your example to create an aspect and created the rule (when items are created or enter this folder or updated, add aspect to all items). However when I click 'Edit properties' on an item in the folder which should have the aspect applied, the new property is not displayed. Do you know why this is? Your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using Share or Explorer? If using share, you need to list all of the properties in C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension\share-config-custom.xml. I'll edit my answer to show what I'm using.

Comment: I am using Share. I copied the code you used above but when I go to add the rule to automatically add the aspect to each item in the required folder the new aspects are not available in the DDL. Also if I try to add the new aspects manually (ie. Manage Aspects -> Add aspect.my_sampleProps -> Apply Changes) I get the error "Could not Update aspects". I'm sure this is probably just something simple I am overlooking.

P.s. You are not wrong about it being "a royal pain in the ass" ;)

Comment: Send me an email at grauenwolf@gmail.com and I'll send you a zip file with my configs.

Comment: I now have no "Could not Update aspects" error message, and can add an aspect manually or based on a rule. However when I click edit properties on an item which has the aspect added I do not see any of the properties which the new aspect should have added. :(

Comment: Managed to get this sorted. Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: @JonathanAllen, why not just update the answer with "zip" content ?

Comment: There were way too many and I had no idea which ones were important. (And I still don't because, thankfully, I don't have to work with this ridiculous software any more.)

Answer (score 3):

The available metadata for a given node in Alfresco are dictated by its [type and aspects](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide).

Alfresco already ships with an EXIF aspect (look [here](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml) for "exif:exif") you might want to use for your use case, which unfortunately the WCM QS hides. You should create a `share-config-custom.xml` file (sample [here](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/slingshot/config/alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml.sample), official [docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/forms-aspect-display.html)) which should list all the fields from the `exif:exif` aspect you want to expose.

Something like the following should work:

```
<config evaluator="model-type" condition="exif:exif">
    <forms>
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="exif:dateTimeOriginal"/>                  
            </field-visibility>             
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What I really want to do is create custom metadata for different types of content within my system. So exposing the different fields in the exif aspect wouldn't really solve this issue. But thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Look at the first link in my answer, that's where the whole explanation on content types and aspects is. You should most likely use aspects to model your needs in this case.